# Create cordova plugin in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I am new in Phonegap based application.
I have to push a method in ObjectiveC class.
I want to create a plugin for this, can any one help me out?
If any one give me the steps to make this done, that will be helpful for me.

Thanks for your cooperation in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See plugin development guide documentation : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Read ALL the doc.

And especially for iOS plugins: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins